# Importar gráficos de planilhas para userform (excel vba)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Tenho que importa 3 gráficos para um userform. Eu até tinha conseguido, mas do nada começou a dar erros, ai coloquei o código "On Error Resume Next" (mas isso não é solução, apenas não trava mais o meu formulário, porém não faz o que deveria fazer). No momento tenho o código abaixo:

```
Sheets("Plan3").Select

On Error Resume Next

Set Grafico = Sheets("Plan3").ChartObjects("Graf").Chart

nome = "C:\Windows\Temp" & Application.PathSeparator & "temp.gif"
Grafico.Export Filename:=nome, Filtername:="GIF"
Imagem1.Picture = LoadPicture(nome)

Sheets("Historico").Select

On Error Resume Next

Set Grafico = Sheets("Historico").ChartObjects("Grafi").Chart

nome = "C:\Windows\Temp" & Application.PathSeparator & "temp.gif"
Grafico.Export Filename:=nome, Filtername:="GIF"
Imagem2.Picture = LoadPicture(nome)

Sheets("KalosG1").Select

On Error Resume Next

Set Grafico = Sheets("KalosG1").ChartObjects("Grafic").Chart

nome = "C:\Windows\Temp" & Application.PathSeparator & "temp.gif"
Grafico.Export Filename:=nome, Filtername:="GIF"
Imagem3.Picture = LoadPicture(nome)
```

Obs: Coloquei "Sheets("....").Select" antes de cada "On Error Resume Next" para tentar resolver, porém não deu certo. Ps: tem horas que funciona tem horas que não. As vezes apenas um dos gráficos falha... Não tenho ideia do que esta errado.

Comment: Ao invés de ignorar o erro (que é o que o comando `On Error Resume Next`) faz, trate o erro! Se o erro está ocorrendo, é porque algum problema existe. Sem você postar qual é esse erro, é impossível alguém te ajudar.

Comment: Coloque o trecho de código em um bloco try / catch, pegue a mensagem da exception e cloque aqui.

Comment: Bom dia Luiz Vieira. Tirei o "On error Resume Next" e o erro que apareceu foi: Erro em tempo de execução '481': Figura inválida

Comment: Bom dia Marcell  Alves. Rapaz, me desculpe a ignorância, mas eu se quer sei o que seria esse bloco try / catch. Porém o erro que apareceu foi: Erro em tempo de execução '481': Figura inválida

Comment: Só pra ter certeza, o diretório "c:\windows\temp" existe, certo? Além disso, os gráficos e planilhas estão com os nomes corretos, certo? Pergunto porque esse erro indica que o `LoadPicture` está falhando, o que pode significar que o código anterior não conseguiu salvar a figura com o gráfico.

Comment: Boa tarde Luiz Vieira. Sim. A principio está tudo certo (tanto que o erro não é continuo... Tem horas que ocorre e horas que não)... Ps: um rapaz disse que isso é uma especie de "bug" (ele não disse exatamente isso) do próprio office. Dai ele sugeriu por: "Grafico.Parent.Select " abaixo da parte: nome = "C:\Windows\Temp" & Application.PathSeparator & "temp.gif" ... Bem, aparenta ter dado certo, desde ontem que não deu mais a falha.